# This webpage has a redirect loop error in CI

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to our live application on my local machine using MAMP. We have Codeigniter application. I am done with the setup. I can access our home page of application e.g. http://dev.myApp.md

But when I try to open http://dev.myApp.md/login it redirects me on http://dev.myApp.md/error page.

Its showing

```
This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Login Controller:

I have tried by:

- Clearing the caches and cookies on browser
- Trying to remove htaccess file
  But its not working. 
  Please help!

  function login_portal($reason=null){

  ```
      $this->load->library('user_agent');
      $this->is_chrome = false;

      $server_type = $this->config->item('server_type');

          if($this->member->checkAuth() && !$this->member->checkSignup()){
          redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
          }

      $data = array();

      $data['username'] = $this->input->get('email');
      $data['notice'] = $this->getLoginErrorMessage($reason);

      $this->load->model('corporate_data');
      $corporate_name_alias = $this->input->get('g');
      $corporate_data = $corporate_name_alias? $this->corporate_data->getCorporationDetails(array('name_alias'=>$corporate_name_alias)) : false;

      $title = ($corporate_data[0]->name)?$corporate_data[0]->name:'Activation Process';
      $all_data = array(
          'page_view'=>'account/login/login_portal',
          'page_data'=>$data,
          'header_data'=>array('script_declarations'=>array('just_validated'=> '',
                                                            'title'         =>$title
                              // 'just_validated' => ($this->db_session->userdata('email_validation_passed'))? 'Thank you for verifying your email.  Please log in below to confirm your account information.':''
                          )
                      ),
          'sections'=>array('nav'=>false,'submenu'=>false)
      );

      if($corporate_data){

          if(strpos($corporate_data[0]->name_alias, 'starbucks')!==FALSE){
              $corporate_data[0]->employee_name = 'partner';
          }else{
              $corporate_data[0]->employee_name = 'employee';
          }
      }

      $all_data['page_data']['corporate_data'] = $corporate_data? $corporate_data[0] : false;
      $all_data['page_view'] = 'account/login/corporate';
      $all_data['header_data']['scripts'] = array('utilities/custom_form_validation', 'utilities/monthdayyear','corporate_login_portal','jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min','activation');
      $all_data['header_data']['stylesheets'] = array('activation');
      $all_data['header_data']['script_declarations']['corporate_data'] = $corporate_data? ((array) $corporate_data[0]): false;

      if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){

          $this->load->view('utilities/login_form_guider');
      }else{
          pr($all_data, 0); 
          loadViews($all_data);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: You are redirecting your all request to login page including login page itself that's the issue. For solution provide some more details.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Indrasinh. Application is hitting the /login page. But on login action we have use loadview() function where we are giving  [page_view] => account/login/corporate parameter.

Comment: can you post yor login controller code?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the code in my post..

Comment: Just for your information.. everything is working on my collegues machine. But issue is my machine itself. So not getting wether its related to htaccess/php conf